# Congruences Ramanujan-style

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, generating-functions, partitions, ramanujan

Let $t\in\Bbb{N}$ and consider the sequences $p_t(n)$ defined by
$$\sum_{n\geq0}p_t(n)x^n=\prod_{i\geq1}\frac1{(1-x^i)^t}=(x;x)_{\infty}^{-t}.$$
The numbers $p_t(n)$ can be regarded as enumerating partitions of $n$ into parts that come with $t$ colors. 
Furthermore, $p_t(n)=\sum_{\lambda\vdash n}\prod_{j\geq1}\binom{k_j+t-1}{t-1}$ where 
$\lambda=1^{k_1}2^{k_2}\cdots$ and each $k_j\geq0$. Note also that $p_1(n)=p(n)$ is the 
usual number of (unrestricted) integer partitions of $n$. Ramanujan's famous congruences state
$$\begin{cases} p(5n+4)\equiv0\mod 5, \\ p(7n+5)\equiv0\mod 7, \\ p(11n+6)\equiv0\mod 11. \end{cases}$$

> In the same spirit, the following appear to be true. Are they?
>   $$\begin{cases} p_t(5n+4)\equiv0\mod 5, \qquad t\equiv0,1,2,4\mod 5 \\ \,p_t(7n+5)\equiv0\mod 7, \qquad \,\,t\equiv0,1,4 \,\,\,\, \mod 7\\ 
> p_t(11n+6)\equiv0\mod 11, \qquad t\equiv0,1,10\mod 11. \end{cases}$$

Comment: Nice. You could add the "generating-functions" and the "ramanujan" tag.

Comment: The cases $t=0,1 \mod p$ ($p=5,7,11$) follow from finite field arithmetic. Indeed, denoting the generating function of $p_1$ by f, we have: $f^{pn_1 + n_0} (x) = f(x^ {p})^{n_1} f(x)^{n_0} \mod p$ for any prime p and $n_0<p$. By comparing coefficients, 
$p_{p n_1 + n_0}(p m_1 + m_0) = \sum_{i=0}^{m_1} p_{n_1}(i)* p_{n_0}(p(m_1 -i)+ m_0) \mod p$ for $m_0 < p$.

In the case of $p=5$ for instance, we may take $n_0=1, m_0=4$  and use Ramamujan's congruences to obtain your result for t=1. For t=0 it is even easier, as it corresponds to $n_0 =  0$, and $p_{0}(j)$ is indicator of 0.

Comment: See also: [(Freeman) Dyson's crank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crank_of_a_partition). It's a great story.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

More general versions of this have been established: see in particular Theorem 2 of [Kiming and Olsson](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01197051.pdf), and for other work see (for example) [Locus and Wagner](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~mlocus/CongruencePPF.pdf).

To answer the question fully, as Ofir Gorodetsky observed the problem is trivial when $t$ is $0$ or $1$ modulo the prime modulus. The other cases correspond to $t \equiv \ell-1$ or $t\equiv \ell-3$ modulo $\ell$ (with $\ell$ being $5$, $7$, or $11$).   These cases are the "non-exceptional congruences" covered by Theorem 2 of the paper by Kiming and Olsson (and the argument there is essentially elementary following easily from Euler's pentagonal number theorem in the case of $\ell-1$, and an identity of Jacobi in the case of $\ell-3$).  The real interest is in the situation of exceptional congruences, and Theorem 4 of Kiming and Olsson gives some examples of these.  For instance, if $t\equiv 3 \mod 11$ then 
$$ 
p_{t}(11n+7) \equiv 0 \pmod{11}. 
$$

Comment: I appreciate the details